# XPath query to return the element with the max length in value

Tags: xml, xpath, string-length

Given a list of elements containing text:

```
<root>
  <element>text text text ...</element>
  <element>text text text ...</element>
<root>
```

I'm trying to write an XPath 1.0 query that will return the element with the max text length.

Unfortunately string-length() returns a single result and not a set, so I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to accomplish using pure XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to write an XPath 1.0 query that will return the element
>   with the max text length

If the number of elements isn't known in advance, it isn't possible to write a single XPath 1.0 expression that selects the element, whose string-length() is the maximum.

**In XPath 2.0 this is trivial**:

```
/*/element[string-length() eq max(/*/element/string-length())]
```

or another way of specifying this, using the general comparison `=` operator:

```
/*/element[string-length() = max(/*/element/string-length())]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but since I found it while looking for a built-in XPath 1.0 solution, perhaps my suggestion might serve someone else, likewise looking for a max-length solution.

If the max length value is needed in an XSLT stylesheet, the value can be found with a template:

```
<!-- global variable for cases when target nodes in different parents. -->
<xsl:variable name="ellist" select="/root/element" />
<!-- global variable to avoid repeating the count for each iteration. -->
<xsl:variable name="elstop" select="count($ellist)+1" />

<xsl:template name="get_max_element">
   <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
   <xsl:param name="max" select="0" />
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$index &lt; $elstop">
         <xsl:variable name="clen" select="string-length(.)" />
         <xsl:call-template name="get_max_element">
            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="($index)+1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="max">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="$clen &gt; &max">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$clen" />
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$max" />
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$max" /></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

`